# Getting the preferred size of an NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I'd like to center an `NSCollectionView` in its enclosing scroll view (horizontally & vertically).

How can I determine the ideal size of the collection view so that all item views fit?

It appears that a collection view will always resize itself to fill the entire document view when enclosed in a scroll view.

Also, if not enclosed in a scroll view, the collection view won't change its frame when new items are added.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to customise the NSCollection View. All you can do is override "drawRect" Method of NSCollectionView and inset its own rect. Below is what will fix your issue

Steps to implement:

1. Create a Class "NSModifiedCollectionView" Where it inherits from NSCollection View and do   the following.

   ```
   @interface NSModifiedCollectionView : NSCollectionView

   @end

   @implementation NSModifiedCollectionView

   - (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
   {
       //You can inset more than 9.0 as per your needs but this will make you fit exactly 
       NSRect insetRec = NSInsetRect(dirtyRect, 9.0, 9.0);

       [super drawRect:insetRec];}
   ```

2: Drag and Drop a NSCollectionView from you object list to the Xib and modify its custom class to **"NSModifiedCollectionView"**. Now Run and check it should work as you expect.

Comment: This does not work. The items are still aligned with the top left edge. This will only inset the background of the collection view. Thanks anyway.